# Why am I so exhausted?

Tags: fifa-12

I've created a Virtual Pro in *FIFA 12* who seems to have a real lack of energy. Even if I play a match as him and never use sprint, he is worn out by the end of the match. After a match of playing, the coach will e-mail a few days after a game telling me he's sitting me out of the next game because of exhaustion. This has happened after every single match so far, about 8 weeks into the season, so I skip every other week.

Is there a way to increase my virtual pro's energy? If there is, in the meantime, is there a way to get the coach to sub me out of a game? I'm playing Career mode as a player, not as a player-coach, or coach.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to sprint or run once your energy bar is depleted. Your stamina will decrease very quickly. Use running and sprinting in bursts rather than all the time; once the energy bar has gone down, let it replenish before doing anything else strenuous! while at zero, your energy level severely affects your stamina.

Also, how to increase your virtual pro's physical attributes (including stamina): 
http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/fifa-10-sony-playstation-3-microsoft-xbox-360/828314-virtual-pro-accomplishments.html 
(under the "physical" heading)

Answer (score 1):

How far in are you? It's probably because your stats aren't very high. As you get better you will have more energy.